# Is there a simple way to tokenize a uri query argument like OData's $filter but without a pre-defined model?

Tags: asp.net, uri, tokenize

I'm building a simple utility that aims to provide a local api for development purposes and which does not have pre-defined entities.  The only endpoint takes the entity name from the url, sanitizes it, and uses it to build a dynamic SQL string for data retrieval.

I would like to be able to support queries similar to OData, but unfortunately OData is not very compatible with this arrangement without a pre-defined entity type.  As for building the SQL to facilitate the functionality I want, most of the OData operators are relatively trivial.  $filter is the main problem.  I've searched through all of the repositories for $filter parsers that I can find which simply tokenize the string without an entity, but most are somewhat outdated and/or have not been finished or maintained well.

At this point, I really just need some simple functionality similar to OData $filter parsing but it really doesn't need to be over the top.  I know that what I'm asking about is possible because javascript has more libraries which do exactly what I'm looking for, and I thought I would ask around before putting in the hours to roll out my own parser.  If there are any good alternatives to OData's $filter parsing which produce a tokenized representation I can use to build an SQL string, guidance would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to rethink my search criteria and additional digging resulted in
DynamicOdataToSQL & SqlKata seamlessly solving this problem.